# after_initializeが先に実行されることにより、joinsやincludesを使ったn+1問題が解消されません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby 2.2.1p85
rails 4.2.1

以下のようなmodel構成で実装しております。

```
class Student
  after_initialize :set_profile
  has_one :student_profile, dependent: :destroy

  def set_profile
    self.student_profile ||= StudentProfile.new
  end
end

class StudentProfile
  belong_to :student
end
```

その上で、n+1問題を解決したく以下のようにすると、先にafter_initializeが発生してしまい、n+1問題が解決しませんでした。

Student.joins(:student_profile)
もしくは
Student.includes(:student_profile)

after_initializeの処理はいじりたくなく、それ以外の方法でn+1問題を解決する方法はありますでしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

やりたいことは、`Student#student_profile` を呼び出した際に必ず `StudentProfile` のインスタンスが返るようにしたい (`nil` にしたくない) ということだと思います。これを実現するため、`student_profile` メソッドを置き換えて、呼ばれた際に初めて初期化する方法があります。

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :student_profile, dependent: :destroy

  def student_profile_with_init
    self.build_student_profile if not self.student_profile_without_init
    self.student_profile_without_init
  end

  alias_method_chain :student_profile, :init
end
```

以上の設定をした上で、`Student.eager_load(:student_profile)` または `Student.includes(:student_profile)` と呼び出すことで、N+1 を回避できます。

**注記**

- `alias_method_chain` によって、`student_profile_with_init` が `student_profile` になり、元のメソッドは `student_profile_without_init` として保存されます。
- `build_student_profile` はアソシエーションによって、自動的に生成されるメソッドで、やっていることは `self.build_student_profile = StudentProfile.new` と同じです。